# Get current windows user of user accessing site

Tags: php, windows, session, cookies

I am making a small app for a team of 5 or 6 people. The team is small enough that a login/authentication system isn't necessary, especially since the app is behind a firewall and only accessible on a specific subnet.

Is there an easy way to grab the windows user of the user accessing the site so that I can make the `createdBy` and `updatedBy` fields use that data?

Possibly in a session or a cookie?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003751/how-do-i-use-microsoft-ad-and-php-single-sign-on-web-app

Comment: This looks like it might be a little more in depth than I need? Using single signon and authentication (which I think were the end results) are a bit more than I am hoping to have my user do. Also, IIS host

Comment: You can either follow the path in the link given to you or you could create a simple login script that works with [LDAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) that will authenticate users against Active Directory which would allow you to get their their username, real name, etc.