# How to setup nginx to authenticate users through Azure AD?

Tags: nginx, oauth, azure-active-directory

I'm using nginx as reverse proxy to protect my server's HTTP endpoints. I want to use Azure AD as authentication provider. How do I make nginx check credentials against Azure AD? Should I use Oauth? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be something https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap
Or else you will have to resort to a php script querying AD returning a token to authenticate a session. Or via Lua https://github.com/Kloadut/SSOwat

Comment: I'd like to avoid building nginx if possible. Sounds like https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy works out of the box. Am I missing something? I know it does not support WebSockets (which is a problem since I want nginx to reverse proxy for Kibana which does need WebSockets, AFAIK).

Comment: oauth2 is a backend solution, same as php would be.

Comment: Almost similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003751/how-do-i-use-microsoft-ad-and-php-single-sign-on-web-app