# How to use SSO in a php written website with apache 2.4?

Tags: php, apache, single-sign-on

I am an intern in a company and have to make an intranet for the company. The difficulty for me is that i am very new to programming and don't really know how apache works. 
The users don't want to log into the intranet (put the login and password) everytime they come on the site, they want them to be logged in without doing that.

All my users use Windows 7 (or  higher), and i will write the intranet in php-sql, using apache server 2.4.

I want to know how i can connect the users by SSO using NTLM (because the authentification is done with Active Driectory, i would like the user to be connected automatically with their Windows login and password)? What is the apache module for that and how do i proceed ? What Library do i use in PHP ?

I really am stuck at this point and can't seem to find a solution, please help me. I found some links that could help me but i don't understand what is the author saying.

Here are some links about the subjects :

- [a forum question](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4548&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0)
- [a wiki article](http://wiki.otterhub.org/index.php?title=Implementing_Single_Sign_On_on_Linux_with_Apache)

Actually i saw that this kind of question  was already asked here ([How can I implement single sign-on (SSO) using Microsoft AD for an internal PHP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003751/how-can-i-implement-single-sign-on-sso-using-microsoft-ad-for-an-internal-php)) but I don't get the solution, I would like someone to explain a little bit in detail as i said before i am very new to programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement single sign-on (SSO) using Microsoft AD for an internal PHP app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003751/how-can-i-implement-single-sign-on-sso-using-microsoft-ad-for-an-internal-php)

Comment: I had checked the response given to the question you are referring to but i don't get the solution given in the answers, could you possibly explain it to me ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all using Apache is not necessary and will complicate things somewhat to do what you are trying to do, if you can use IIS server on one of your Windows servers you will be laughing.

1. Install PHP on the IIS server
2. Create a new website in IIS
3. Set the new websites access to Windows Authentication and disable anonomouse access.

What this will do is configure IIS to authenticate the users against Active Directory, if they are on a Windows machine on the local network, already authenticated to the local domain, and the intranet is defined by GPO as a intranet site then the users Windows login details will be automatically passed and can be accessed in PHP using the `$_SERVER` superglobal.